# How can four be the half of five?

Tags: wordplay, number-property

I came across this enigmatic one-liner:

> How can four be half of five?

Can you figure it out?

Comment: Having seen the answer, I think the following phrasing would make make for a better, less ambiguous puzzle: How can 5 be half of 4, and 4 be half of five?

Comment: Why am I getting close votes?

Comment: The close votes so far all give the reason that the question invites speculative answers ( [see this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254/20814) ). I'm afraid my previous comment may have triggered that. Personally, I disagree. When the tags are taken into account none of the alternative answers can be correct. My phrasing would nail it down a bit more without the need for tags, but that does not mean that the question is not specific enough as is.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: I think it would be more clear without the word "the".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One answer that springs to mind

> **IV** (Roman numeral for 4) is half of F**IV**E

Comment: @HexagonalImpossibilities. A suggestion. As a courtesy to puzzle solvers, who prefer to solve it without looking at a direct answer, please use rot13 to hide your comment. Seems like it gives the answer out.

Comment: Thank you, did not think of that! but I can't edit my earlier answer, dunno why...

Comment: @HexagonalImpossibilities then four's half of four!

Comment: @user253751 indeed

Comment: @infinitezero thanks for your suggestion, though I personally prefer [this tool](https://cryptii.com/). Anyway, @ hexomino, my reasoning was "rot13Pbaireg 4 gb ebzna. VI ner 2 yrggref, juvyr svir ner 4 yrggref. Sbhe vf gur unys bs svir!". But yours is close enough and also logical, so yeah.

Answer (score 21):

If you make a pentagon,

```
/ \  
|_|
```

and you cut it in half from top to bottom you get:

```
 /|  |\  
|_|  |_|
```

that is, you get two shapes with four corners each.

Answer (score 13):

Another (kind of linguistic) answer:

> Since the word *half*, at least historically, means "one of two *approximately* equal parts" (for example, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half) gives the following example:  *“Which half do you want?” “I'll take the smaller half.”*), we can say the following: **Four is the half of five, as long as one is the other half of it!**

Comment: I'm certain that one of those upvotes is my taxman.

Answer (score 8):

Four is the half of five if five is two times four. Considering the multiplicative group of integers modulo $3$, we have:

$$
2 * 4 \equiv_3 8 \equiv_3 5
$$

So five *is* two times four. And so four is half of five.

Answer (score 7):

There are literally an *infinite* number of solutions of the form:

> In the list `{25, 25, 25, 25, 100}`, four is the half of five :-)

Comment: @infinitezero rot13(Sbhe vgrzf (sbhe gjragl svirf) ner unys bs svir vgrzf (sbhe gjragl svirf naq bar uhaqerq), nf gurfr gbtrgure znxr gjb uhaqerq.)

Comment: Well, four *are* the half of five.

Answer (score -1):

If you draw 5 in Roman Numerals and then draw a line cutting it in half, you get the Arabic numeral 4 (upside down) perhaps?

```
\  |
 \ |
  \|

\ /|
 X |
/ \|

 /|
/-+-
  |
```

Answer (score -2):

> Take 4 in binary: `100`
> Take away zero, twice (4-0-0 = 4): `1`
> Take 5 in binary: `101`
> Take away zero, once (5-0 = 5): `11`
> Obvious mathematics is obvious. Why are you troubling me with this?